# Is a user with "Contributor" and "User Access Administrator" roles same as a user with "Owner" role?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rbac

So we have got 3 built-in roles: [`Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#owner), [`Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) and [`User Access Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#user-access-administrator).

Considering a `Contributor` can do everything in an Azure Subscription except RBAC role assignment and a `User Access Administrator` can do RBAC role assignment, can we assume that if a user is assigned both `Contributor` and `User Access Administrator` roles at a particular scope (e.g. Subscription), they are effectively an Owner for that scope?

Or are there certain things that still only an `Owner` can do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at the permissions:

- A Owner can do anything: `"actions": ["*"]`.
- A User Admin can only read anything (except secret), manage roles and create and update support tickets: `"actions": ["*/read", "Microsoft.Authorization/*", "Microsoft.Support/*"]`
- A contributor can do anything except managing roles, managing blueprint assignment and sharing a gallery to different scopes

  ```
  "actions": [
    "*"
  ],
  "notActions": [
    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Delete",
    "Microsoft.Authorization/*/Write",
    "Microsoft.Authorization/elevateAccess/Action",
    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/write",
    "Microsoft.Blueprint/blueprintAssignments/delete",
    "Microsoft.Compute/galleries/share/action"
  ],
  ```

So a user with `Contributor` and `User Access Administrator` roles is missing some permissions compared to the `Owner` Role: Can't create/delete blueprint and can't share gallery to different scopes